# Anonym password protect pages without username with Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have to implement a very simple user authentication for a Flask project where users can access to the protected pages without usernames. I already checked the [Flask-BasicAuth](http://flask-basicauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension, but it's too "much", you need usernames to use it. I just want to declare a list in my flask file that contains passwords as a string that can be used for accessing to a particular page and it's sub pages.

So my goal is to achieve something like this:

1. User arrives to `xy.com/protected-page` and uses a password from `passwords = ['pass1', 'pass2', 'pass3']` (that are static and not stored in a database)
2. After a successful login he/she will be able to see `xy.com/protected-page`, `xy.com/protected-page/sub-page1, xy.com/protected-page/sub-page2` etc...

It would be a really great bonus if I could set a session time.

Is it possible? I'm quite new to Flask, so I would appreciate if somebody could help me out.

Comment: Yes, all of that is possible. What have you tried? What specific problems are you having? Please edit your question to contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using [Flask-Login](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login) with the caveat of generic usernames. That said there is an `AnonymousUserMixin` class available, which might be exactly what you are looking for.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
import flask.ext.login as flask_login
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, UserMixin

login_manager = LoginManager()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'key'

login_manager.init_app(app)

users = {'user1':{'pw':'pass1'}, 
         'user2':{'pw':'pass2'}, 
         'user3':{'pw':'pass3'}}

class User(UserMixin):
  pass

@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(username):
  if username not in users:
    return

  user = User()
  user.id = username
  return user

@login_manager.request_loader
def request_loader(request):
  username = request.form.get('username')
  if username not in users:
    return

  user = User()
  user.id = username

  user.is_authenticated = request.form['pw'] == users[username]['pw']

  return user



@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form.get('username')
    if request.form.get('pw') == users[username]['pw']:
      user = User()
      user.id = username
      flask_login.login_user(user)
      return redirect(url_for('protect'))
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/protect')
@flask_login.login_required
def protect():
  return render_template('protected.html')

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
  flask_login.logout_user()
  return 'Logged out'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

*templates/index.html*:

```
<html>
  <title>Test</title>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <form method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='username'>Username</input>
    <input type='password' name='pw'>Password</input>
    <input type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</input>
  </form>
</html>
```

*templates/protected.html*

```
<html>
  <title>Test</title>
  <h1>Protected</h1>
</html>
```

*project structure*

```
.
├── app.py
└── templates
    ├── index.html
    └── protected.html
```

Comment: It's working perfectly! I will check AnonymousUserMixin, huge thanks!

Comment: You might want this instead: `from flask.ext.login import login_required`. It's a trivial change but then you can decorate your view functions with just `@login_required`.

Comment: I think there should be username key check for the users dictionary at index method, just above request.form.get('pw') == users[username]['pw']: line

Comment: Not sure what you mean @AliYeşilkanat. It's not intended to be perfect code, rather a simple example demonstrating the concept. For which it satisfies the requirement.